# Move text outside of the container vertically

Tags: javascript, css

I have DIV with some CSS styling and TEXT inside DIV. How to move TEXT outside of DIV and apply some styling using either CSS or JavaScript?

**HTML**

```
<div class="divstyle">TEXT</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.divstyle {
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: grey;
}
```

**I create complete DIV over javascript:**

```
var inputfield = document.createElement("div");
inputfield.textContent = inputfieldData['TEXT'];
inputfield.classList.add("divstyle");
inputfieldsContainer.appendChild(inputfield);
```

**When it renders in browser it looks like this:**

```
+-----------------+
| TEXT            |
+-----------------+
```

**I wish to be like this:**

```
TEXT
+-----------------+
|                 |
+-----------------+
```

**What I tried:**

```
.divstyle::before {
    top: -50px;
    left: -20px;
}
```

Is there a way to add DIV inside DIV using only CSS?
Maybe the solution could be to wrap the TEXT in some tag and apply CSS to it, but if it's possible to do it over CSS?

Comment: Why would you want to display the contents of a container outside said container?

Comment: I think it will be simple to place a <p/> with your text and then the gray <div/>

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Instead of setting the text inside div, you can set the content of the pseudo-element as 'TEXT' and do the following.

```
<div class="divstyle"></div>
.divstyle {
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: grey;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 50px;
}

.divstyle::before{
    content: 'TEXT';
    position: absolute;
    top: -50%;
}
```

https://codepen.io/caglar62/pen/LYgaPPW

Comment: I was thinking the same, but do not know how to use JavaScript to add content property to .divstyle::before.

Comment: @user21955191 please check this example: https://codepen.io/felquis/pen/JjMEEG

Answer (score 0):

It is not entirely clear what you want, maybe something like this will suit you:

```css
div {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
}

div:after {
  content: '';
  border: dashed 1px;
}
```

```html
<div>TEXT</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Although I don't understand why you want this, here is two ways to achieve it :

1. First way :

HTML

```
<div class="divstyle">
  <span class="out">TEXT</span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.divstyle {
  position: relative;
  background-color: grey;
}
.out {
  position: relative;
  top: -1em;
}
```

2/ Second way (after reading your first comment) :

HTML

```
<div class="divstyle" content="TEXT">&nbsp;</div>
```

CSS

```
.divstyle {
  background-color: grey;
}
.divstyle:before {
  content: attr(content);
  position: absolute;
  top: -1em;
}
```

Comment: I can't change DIV structure. is there a way to use CSS content property?

Comment: I edited my answer to make a new try with content property...

Comment: I figure out the way.. I just need help to put it in code. So.. in CSS, create .divstyle::before with content: as you did in Second way. but not changing DIV. leave it as it is. Then in javascript get innerText and put it in div.setAttribute('content', what you get from innerText)... then just remove TEXT from DIV with javascript..

Answer (score -1):

You could add a span using another styling (here: textstyle)

```
<div class="divstyle">
    <span class="textstyle">
        TEXT
    </span>
</div>
```

which could look like that

```
    .textstyle {
        position: absolute;
        top: -20px;
        font-size: 24px;
    }
```

The important part to notice here is that position is set to absolute, so you can position it relative to its first positioned  ancestor element.

Comment: I can't change the DIV structure. I tried in css with line-height set to 0, but the text goes up only for half of text height.

Comment: You'd also need `position: relative;` on the `.divstyle` to ensure that the `div` actually _is_ the first positioned ancestor element.